# DI Container and custom-scoped state in legacy system

Tags: dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ioc-container, state, legacy-code

I believe I understand the basic concepts of DI / IoC containers having written a couple of applications using them and reading a lot of stack overflow answers as well as Mark Seeman's book. There are still some cases that I have trouble with, especially when it comes to integrating DI container to a large existing architecture where DI principle hasn't been really used (think big ball of mud).

I know the ideal scenario is to have a single composition root / object graph per operation but in a legacy system this might not be possible without major refactoring (only the new and some select refactored old parts of the code could have dependencies injected through constructor and the rest of the system using the container as a service locator to interact with the new parts). This effectively means that a stack trace deep within an operation might include several object graphs with calls being made back and forth between new subsystems (single object graph until exiting into an old segment) and traditional subsystems (service locator call at some point to code under DI container).

With the (potentially faulty, I might be overthinking this or be completely wrong in assuming this kind of hybrid architecture is a good idea) assumptions out of the way, here's the actual problem:

Let's say we have a thread pool executing scheduled jobs of various types defined in database (or any external place). Each separate type of scheduled job is implemented as a class inheriting a common base class. When the job is started, it gets fed the information about which targets it should write its log messages to and the configuration it should use. The configuration could probably be handled by just passing the values as method parameters to whatever class needs them but if the job implementation gets larger than say 10-20 classes, it doesn't seem very handy.

Logging is the larger problem. Subsystems the job calls probably also need to write things to the log and usually in examples this is done by just requesting instance of ILog in the constructor. But how does that work in this case when we don't know the details / implementation until runtime? Since:

- Due to (non DI container controlled) legacy system segments in the call chain (-> there potentially being multiple separate object graphs), child container cannot be used to inject the custom logger for specific sub-scope
- Manual property injection would basically require the complete call chain (including all legacy subsystems) to be updated

A simplified example to help better perceive the problem:

```
Class JobXImplementation : JobBase {
    // through constructor injection
    ILoggerFactory _loggerFactory;
    JobXExtraLogic _jobXExtras;

    public void Run(JobConfig configurationFromDatabase)
    {
        ILog log = _loggerFactory.Create(configurationFromDatabase.targets);
        // if there were no legacy parts in the call chain, I would register log as instance to a child container and Resolve next part of the call chain and everyone requesting ILog would get the correct logging targets
        // do stuff
        _jobXExtras.DoStuff(configurationFromDatabase, log);
    }
}

Class JobXExtraLogic {
    public void DoStuff(JobConfig configurationFromDatabase, ILog log) {
        // call to legacy sub-system
        var old = new OldClass(log, configurationFromDatabase.SomeRandomSetting);
        old.DoOldStuff();
    }
}

Class OldClass {
    public void DoOldStuff() {
        // moar stuff 
        var old = new AnotherOldClass();
        old.DoMoreOldStuff();
    }
}

Class AnotherOldClass {
    public void DoMoreOldStuff() {
        // call to a new subsystem 
        var newSystemEntryPoint = DIContainerAsServiceLocator.Resolve<INewSubsystemEntryPoint>();
        newSystemEntryPoint.DoNewStuff();
    }
}

Class NewSubsystemEntryPoint : INewSubsystemEntryPoint {
    public void DoNewStuff() {
        // want to log something...
    }
}
```

I'm sure you get the picture by this point.

Instantiating old classes through DI is a non-starter since many of them use (often multiple) constructors to inject values instead of dependencies and would have to be refactored one by one. The caller basically implicitly controls the lifetime of the object and this is assumed in the implementations (the way they handle internal object state).

What are my options? What other kinds of problems could you possibly see in a situation like this? Is trying to only use constructor injection in this kind of environment even feasible?

Comment: My first though about logging is: [aren't you logging too much?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9892137/windsor-pulling-transient-objects-from-the-container/9915056#9915056)

Answer (score 1):

Great question. In general, I would say that an IoC container loses a lot of its effectiveness when only a portion of the code is DI-friendly.

Books like [Working Effectively with Legacy Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131177052) and [Dependency Injection in .NET](http://www.manning.com/seemann/) both talk about ways to tease apart objects and classes to make DI viable in code bases like the one you described.

Getting the system under test would be my first priority. I'd pick a functional area to start with, one with few dependencies on other functional areas.

I don't see a problem with moving beyond constructor injection to setter injection where it makes sense, and it might offer you a stepping stone to constructor injection. Adding a property is usually less invasive than changing an object's constructor.