# c# How to Inject dependency on a custom handler for WebAPI using ninject

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, ninject

I have the following handler for my c# `WebAPI` project.

```
public class CustomLogHandler : DelegatingHandler
    {
        [Inject]
        public ILogRepository LogRepository { get; set; }

        ... some methods here   
     }
```

This handler is registered in my `WebApiConfig.cs` class.

```
public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            ... some code here

            config.MessageHandlers.Add(new CustomLogHandler());
        }
}
```

Also my ILogRepository is registered in my `NinjectWebCommon.cs` class as my other repositories:

```
 kernel.Bind(typeof(ILogRepository)).To(typeof(Data.LogRepository));
```

> The problem is that when I debug and the breakpoint hits my `CustomLogHandler` method, `LogRepository` instance is null.

Any clue?

Comment: Register the handler with the kernel as well and then resolve the instance before adding it to the handler collection

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inject dependency into DelegatingHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14756519/inject-dependency-into-delegatinghandler)

Answer (score 0):

I found a way that works great:

```
var service = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver.GetService(typeof(ILogRepository)) as ILogRepository;
```

Hope this works for someone else.

Thanks