# Dependency Resolver using unity for singleton class

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, singleton

I am having an ILogger interface and Logger class(which is singleton) implements ILogger interface. I wanted to register this dependency using unity container. Could you please help me out.

```
public class Logger: ILogger
{
 private static readonly Lazy<Logger> instance = new Lazy<Logger>(()=> new Logger());
 public static Logger Instance{get{return instance.Value;}}
 private Logger(){}
 public void LogEvent(){}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I see your code not compilable. Your missed type of the Instance:

```
...
public static ILogger Instance {get{return instance.Value;}}
...
```

As I understand your intension, try next in your startup class:

```
var container = new UnityContainer();
var logger = Logger.Instance; 
container.RegisterInstance<ILogger>(logger, new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```

`container.Resolve<ILogger>` returns your instance and inject `ILogger` in a constructor and you should get your logger instance
`ContainerControlledLifetimeManager` resolves a singleton instance of the registered type scoped to the lifetime of the container.

Do not forget setup UnityContainer as the default dependency resolver in your project.

Comment: Thanks @luriiMaksimov. I have missed the return type for Instance. The instance is created once through logger. Still do I need to add ContainerControlledLifetimeManager()?

Comment: @thegautamnayak In majority yes. It's needed. This is instruction for unity to keep your instance safety and protects it from runtime changes until you call RegisterInstance again. I pretty sure creators had some idea behind the scene implementing this.

Comment: Thanks a ton @Iurii-maksimov. one more question :) I am using this inside a filter and that filter is registered in the webapiconfig.cs file. Now how can i inject the logger object to that filter?

Comment: @thegautamnayak Glad to help you. Please mark my answer as a correct one. Make it green :). According to how registered -> you should have something like this: HttpConfiguration config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration; var container = new UnityContainer();
/* your registrations */
config.DependencyResolver = new UnityResolver(container); And for config.Filters - just reuse you Logger.Instance. But it depends how you build an app

Comment: do i need to pass the instance like below?config.MessageHandlers.Add(new TestHandler(Logger.Instance));

Comment: @thegautamnayak Ok, then its not a filter but message handelr. Yes, you can do this. This is one possible way. Check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14756519/inject-dependency-into-delegatinghandler There're answers.

Comment: Thanks a ton. It really helped me a lot :)