# How to use transient logger in singleton classes, Simple Injector

Tags: c#, logging, dependency-injection, log4net, simple-injector

I have a LogManager class which has a type parameter to give to log4net like this:

```
public class LogManager<T> : ILogManager
{
    private ILog Logger { get; set; }

    public LogManager()
    {
        Logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(T));
    }
}
```

And I register this logger as conditional:

```
container.RegisterConditional(typeof(ILogManager),
c => typeof(LogManager<>).MakeGenericType(c.Consumer.ImplementationType),
Lifestyle.Transient,
c => true);
```

It works like it supposed to, I inject the log manager to my controllers' constuctors and use it. But there is a problem. I have a lot of singleton classes that should use the log manager too, but I can't inject it to them because log manager has a shorter life then others, so Simple Injector won't allow me to do it.

The proposed solution is to inject a log factory class to the other singletons and call the factory every time which sounds like a bad idea. I don't want to do **_logFactory.GetLogger().Debug("log")** every time I want to log something. Or I am missing something about this solution?

The other proposed solution is to make singleton classes transient which doesn't make any sense.

Any suggestions how should I proceed? Is there anything wrong with my design?

Comment: Sooo... why don't you just register that `LogManager<T>` as singleton?

Comment: If I do that I lost the class info which does the logging.

Comment: Have you tested this? Log4net's Logger classes are thread-safe, and each `T` will get its own `LogManager<T>` instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should make the registration singleton:

```
container.RegisterConditional(typeof(ILogManager),
    c => typeof(LogManager<>).MakeGenericType(c.Consumer.ImplementationType),
    Lifestyle.Singleton,
    c => true);
```

Since `LogManager<>` is a generic type, Simple Injector will create one instance per closed generic version. So `LogManager<HomeController>` is a different instance than `LogManager<UsersController>`. This is simply because there is no way to use the same instance (this is impossible in .NET). So each consumer will still have its own `LogManager<T>` and with that its own log4net `ILog` implementation. The loggers returned from log4net's `LogManager.GetLogger` are thread-safe, and that's why its no problem to make your own `LogManager<T>` singleton.

Comment: You are rigth, I was a little confused about this. Wouldn't it be a problem to have more than 300 controllers which means more than 300 different logger instances?

Comment: @gmmm From a perspective of memory consumption, there will hardly be a problem, but you absolutely do have a maintainability problem when you inject your logger into so many classes. Please read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9915056/264697)

Comment: that was the answer that got me thinking :) I will try to simplify the classes.