# How can I inject an object into a static method?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, dapper

I have a .net core 5 application that has an `appsettings.json` file, in which I have listed connection strings to the databases.

I have defined a `Database` class that has the responsibility of handing out `IDbConnection` objects.

```
public class Database
{
    public Database(IConfiguration config) // config is injected 
    {
        Db1ConnectionString = config.GetConnectionString("db1");
        Db2ConnectionString = config.GetConnectionString("db2");
    }

    public IDbConnection GetConnection() 
    {
        // do some logic to decide, either Db1 or Db2 to use
        return new SQLiteConnection(SelectedDbConnectionString);
    }
}
```

Then I am injecting this `Database` in `Startup.cs`

```
services.AddScoped<IDatabase, Database>();    // IDatabase is interface of Database
```

Let's say I have a class of `Person`

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I am using Dapper to fetch `IEnumerable<Person>`. I am writing logic to fetch collections of objects in the same class itself. Meaning: Person class knows how to fetch a collection of its self. `Animal` class has its own logic of fetching a collection of its self.

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public static IEnumerable<Person> GetAll()
    {
         string sql = "select id, name from person where ...... ";
         using var con = Database.GetConnection();   // this does not work
                 // because the GetConnection() is not static.
         return con.Query<Person>(sql);
    }

}
```

The code above will not work because I need an instance of `Database` inside a static method. I though of injecting `Database` in `Person` constructor, but that will make things difficult for Dapper. So I guess I will need to write an empty constructor for `Person`. But then the other constructor (that acceptes `IDatabase` ) can't keep hold of the reference of that database object until the static method requires it.

I thought of converting `Database` into a static class, or changing `GetConnection()` into static method, but then I will not be able to inject it in `Startup.cs`.

I don't want to hardcore the connection strings, as they may change at run time.

I feel like there is a straight forward solution to this problem, and it must be obvious too.

Comment: by not making it static ... just add `IPersonDataService` and `PersonDataService` (or whatever) implementation  ... then inject `IDatabase` to the constructor

Comment: How will this allow me to use the connection object in the static method? can you please elaborate? @Selvin

Comment: Do not use static method at all!

Comment: @Selvin if I don't use a static method, then how would I be able to call a method that it is defined in the `Person` class which returns a collection of `Person`?

Comment: again ... there should be no such method it should be a part of `IPersonDataService`

Comment: Thanks. If you want, please write a proper answer, so that I can accept it. Otherwise, I will delete this question. @Selvin

Comment: I agree with @Selvin here. 1. such `GetAll` method should never be static, as it becomes impossible to properly loosely couple your code, and 2. `GetAll` should not be part of `Person` as person will be part of your domain layer, while the `GetAll` logic will reside in your data access layer. So as Selvin is mentioning, define a separate abstraction (e.g. `IPersonRepository` or `IPersonDataService`), define the `GetAll` method on it, create an implementation that gets the database injected, and inject that abstraction again in classes that need to call `GetAll`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you require a dependency inside a static method, you'll end up with Method Injection, as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52325438/how-to-inject-dependency-to-static-class) describes. This means that your `Person` class becomes the following:

```cs
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
 
    // IDatabase is supplied using Method Injection
    public static IEnumerable<Person> GetAll(IDatabase database)
    {
         string sql = "select id, name from person where ...... ";
         using var con = database.GetConnection();
         return con.Query<Person>(sql);
    }
}
```

Consequence of method injection, however, is that the dependency (i.e. `IDatabase`) is no longer hidden to the consumers, but instead need to be *supplied* by them. e.g.:

```cs
public sealed class PersonService : IPersonService
{
    private readonly IDatabase database;
    
    public PersonService(IDatabase database)
    {
        this.database = database;
    }

    public void ChangeName(int id, string newName)
    {
        var persons = Person.GetAll(this.database);
        var person = persons.Single(p => p.Id == id);
        person.Name = newName;
        person.Save(this.database);
    }
}
```

In practice, this means that those consumers should either get this dependency injected into them either using Constructor Injection or Method Injection. The previous example with `PersonService` shows Constructor Injection.

Having to supply dependencies through Method Injection can be unpractical for many reasons: first of all, it complicates consumers with an extra dependency, as the example above shows.

The use of such static method is probably not the best solution. However, making the method an instance method, on the other hand, is also not practical, because:

- It means you'll have to inject `IDatabase` into `Person`, but that complicates the creation of `Person` instances, as they are typically created by your O/RM mapper (e.g. Entity Framework). Also, you are injecting a dependency that is only needed in the case that `GetAll` is being called.
- It is very weird to have to instantiate a specific `Person` in order to get all persons. e.g.:

  ```cs
  var person = new Person(database);
  return person.GetAll(); // Get all of what? Persons of that person?
  ```
- When you start injecting `IDatabase` into person, you'll soon end up with a dozen or more dependencies into `Person`, because you likely add many more person-related methods in this class. eg.:

  ```cs
  var person = new Person(database, timeProvider, userContext)
  {
      Id = 100,
      Name = "Steven"
  };
  // Save might require the current time and the user executing the operation
  return person.Save();
  ```

This might lead to the conclusion that having this `GetAll` method on `Person` method not be the best solution. Rather than placing this method (and many others) inside `Person`, it could be cleaner to separate the concerns of data access and your domain entity.

A very common pattern that is used for such situations is the Repository Pattern. There are several variations of this pattern, but in essence you define a separate interface for your data-access logic. This was already suggested in the comments by @Selvin and me. For instance, you can define an `IPersonRepository` interface:

```
public interface IPersonRepository
{
    IEnumerable<Person> GetAll();
    void Save(Person person);
}
```

This allows moving the data access logic into separate class:

```cs
public sealed class SqlPersonRepository : IPersonRepository
{
    private readonly IDatabase database;

    public SqlPersonRepository(IDatabase database)
    {
        this.database = database;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Person> GetAll()
    {
         string sql = "select id, name from person where ...... ";
         using var con = this.database.GetConnection();
         return con.Query<Person>(sql);
    }

    public void Save(Person person) ... 
}
```

Advantage of separating this logic from the `Person` class, is that allows you to place the `Person` class and the `IPersonRepository` inside your Domain layer project, while you keep the `SqlPersonRepository` implementation hidden from the domain layer by placing it inside your Data Access layer project (where this project takes a dependency on the Domain layer project).

Obvious consequence of this design is that any class that requires getting all persons, needs to get `IPersonRepository` injected into it. But when you are practicing Dependency Injection, this will typically not be a problem, and actually something that is encouraged. This can be demonstrated in a changed version of the previous `PersonService`:

```cs
public sealed class PersonService : IPersonService
{
    private readonly IPersonRepository repository;
    
    public PersonService(IPersonRepository repository)
    {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    public void ChangeName(int id, string newName)
    {
        var persons = this.repository.GetAll();
        var person = persons.Single(p => p.Id == id);
        person.Name = newName;
        this.repository.Save(person);
    }
}
```